# How to do with XML same as DbContext and DbSet with Local database in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two classes in Model. One with fields of object and another derived from DbContext that has DbSet of objects of first class. The name of second class is identical as name of instance of LocalDB in Visual Studio.
In Controller I have instantiating of second class from model, and then in index action just: return View(db.Products.ToList()); (Products is name of DbSet, and db is the instance of class derived from DbContext which contains that DbSet). Then in the view the Model is used to get data from.

Is there some method to do simple programming like this for using data from XML file? Is there class like DbContext (and DbSet) that will give derived class power to get data from XML just by instantiating it and at the end to be parameter for view as written above ...ToList()?

Comment: To me it is unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: How to read from XML file data in most similar way as from LocalDB in Visual Studio? For reading from DB I used class derived from DbContext.

Comment: What about DataSet ds = new DataSet();  ds.ReadXml or ds.WriteXml?

Comment: OK, but in ds I don't have DbSet Products that I can pass to view as parameter. There I have return View (db.Products.ToList()). What do I have here ds."what?".ToList()?

Comment: More precisely: How to get something like @model IEnumerable<MVCProduct.Models.Product> ready as collection of objects Product, from XML file, ready for use in view?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution that works using type of List instead of DbSet.